# Extract a block from an 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose you have a 2D array filled with integers in a continuous manner, going from left to right and top to bottom. Hence it would look like

```
[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
 [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Suppose now you have a 1D array of some of the integers shown in the array above. Lets say this array is `[6,7,11]`. I want to extract the block/chunk of the 2D array that contains the elements of the list. With these two inputs the result should be

```
[[ 6.,  7.],
 [11., nan]]
```

(I am padding with `np.nan` is it cannot be reshaped)

This is what I have written. Is there a simpler way please?

```
import numpy as np
def my_fun(my_list):
    ids_down = 4
    ids_across = 5
    layout = np.arange(ids_down * ids_across).reshape((ids_down, ids_across))

    ids = np.where((layout >= min(my_list)) & (layout <= max(my_list)), layout, np.nan)
    r,c = np.unravel_index(my_list, ids.shape)
    out = np.nan*np.ones(ids.shape)
    for i, t in enumerate(zip(r,c)):
        out[t] = my_list[i]

    ax1_mask = np.any(~np.isnan(out), axis=1)
    ax0_mask = np.any(~np.isnan(out), axis=0)
    out = out[ax1_mask, :]
    out = out[:, ax0_mask]

    return out
```

Then trying `my_fun([6,7,11])` returns

```
[[ 6.,  7.],
 [11., nan]]
```

Comment: Is the selection always contiguous? E.g., is [ 6,  7, 11, 19] allowed?

Comment: With @DYZ's example will the correct answer contain a column of nans for the [8,13,18]-column or not?

Comment: @DYZ, yes not contiguous could happen

Comment: @Paul, for this kind of input the result would be the same as the input but transposed ie [8,13,18] as a column which is what DYZ code gives (and yours too). I dont think i get any nans back from DYZ example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 100% NumPy solution works for both contiguous and non-contiguous arrays of wanted numbers.

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
n = np.array([6, 7, 11])
```

Identify the locations of the wanted numbers:

```
mask = np.isin(a, n)
```

Select the rows and columns that have the wanted numbers:

```
np.where(mask, a, np.nan)\
       [mask.any(axis=1)][:, mask.any(axis=0)]
#array([[ 6.,  7.],
#       [11., nan]])
```

Comment: Thank you all for your time to look into this. All very interesting approaches. DYZ replicates my logic, the others are very very close and should work for most people fine especially for non-contiguous cases. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to look for the [bounding boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) by checking which elements in the array are contained in the second list. We can use [`scipy.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html):

```
from scipy import ndimage

m = np.isin(a, b)
a_components, _ = ndimage.measurements.label(m, np.ones((3, 3)))
bbox = ndimage.measurements.find_objects(a_components)
out = a[bbox[0]]
np.where(np.isin(out, b), out, np.nan)

array([[ 6.,  7.],
       [11., nan]])
```

---

Setup -

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

b = np.array([6,7,11])
```

---

Or for `b = np.array([10,12,16])` we'd get:

```
m = np.isin(a, b)
a_components, _ = ndimage.measurements.label(m, np.ones((3, 3)))
bbox = ndimage.measurements.find_objects(a_components)
out = a[bbox[0]]
np.where(np.isin(out, b), out, np.nan)

array([[10., nan, 12.],
       [nan, 16., nan]])
```

---

We could also adapt the above for *multiple bounding boxes* by doing:

```
b = np.array([5, 11, 8, 14])

m = np.isin(a, b)
a_components, _ = ndimage.measurements.label(m, np.ones((3, 3)))
bbox = ndimage.measurements.find_objects(a_components)

l = []
for box in bbox:
    out = a[box]
    l.append(np.where(np.isin(out, b), out, np.nan))

print(l)

[array([[ 5., nan],
        [nan, 11.]]), 
 array([[ 8., nan],
        [nan, 14.]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of the specific form of template array `A` we can directly transform the test values to coordinates:

```
A = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
test = [6,7,11]

y,x = np.unravel_index(test,A.shape)
yl,yr = y.min(),y.max()
xl,xr = x.min(),x.max()
out = np.full((yr-yl+1,xr-xl+1),np.nan)
out[y-yl,x-xl]=test
out
# array([[ 6.,  7.],
#        [11., nan]])
```

Comment: Does not work for non-contiguous selections (e.g., [6,  7, 11, 19]). Not sure if this is important, just FYI.

Comment: @DYZ Depends on what you consider a block/chunk. But you are right in that this does not do 100% the same as OP's code.

Comment: @DYZ true but it is not very hard to rectify that I think